# how to enable hg rebase

Tags: mercurial, rebase

I added these lines to hgrc in my .hg folder:

```
[extension]
rebase =
```

but hg rebase still returns an error: Unknow command 'rebase'.
It may be a dumb question but do I need to include the path to rebase extension after the "=" ? and if yes, where can I find the extension's location?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The heading for the section should be `extensions`, not `extension`.